# How to make MDIChild Transparent?

Tags: c#, transparency, mdi

I'd successfully made a normal Form Transparent by handling the OPACITY property.

Now, I want to make an MDIChild (loaded in an MDIParent) transparent. Is that possible? I'd applied the same technique (mentioned above) for the MDIChild. But, was unsucessful.

Is it possible to make the MDIChild tranparent. Does anyone had done that before?

Any hekp will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No. MDI child forms do not support transparency.

Comment: Is there any hacking techniques, so that I can simulate the same.
What about injecting an umanaged code? does that could do some job?

Comment: No hacks, the Windows API simply doesn't support it.  Only TopLevel windows like the MDI parent can have the TransparencyKey or Opacity property set.

Comment: I've gone through 2 threads in MSDN. 
a) http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/30e73869-58cb-4f01-b539-174ce2ad8e0f

b)http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vclanguage/thread/954ff6f4-88d2-4b6b-ac10-dcf0b94627e1 

which talks about MDI transparency. Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: can this be achieved using WPF?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Region` property.

```
this.Region = this.CreateNewRegion();
// ...
private Region CreateNewRegion() {
   var points = new Point[] { new Point(0,0), new Point(20,0), new Point(30, 50) };
   var path = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicPath();
   path.AddPolygon( points );
   var region = new Region( path );
   return region;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You May try assigning the mdiparent to a form variable, set the mdichild's mdiparent property to null and then apply your technique to make it transparent
. i dont know if it would work